# How to filter JSON/GeoJSON data server-side?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, server-side-rendering, react-leaflet

I have a two large json/geojson files which I extracted from overpassturbo-eu.

I am trying to plot/add as layer this data set on the OSM.

I need to filter the data sets on different zoom levels.

These files are too big to efficiently download the whole file for client-side analysis of the data set.

Is there an efficient way to filter these data sets server-side?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what tools you have available on your server. Do you plan on using Javascript (maybe with nodejs) on the server as well? Do you have shell access?

Comment: At the moment I have plain html and javascript. I don't have shell access. I don't really know how to run a node.js app in my server. It would be really nice if you have any reference. Is there any other way to do the filtering? Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't have shell access, it's going to be hard to make a server at all.  Maybe you can find a way to make queries to the overpass-api to get your OSM data: http://overpass-api.de/index.html